# Git push multiple accounts

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have setup two github accounts in the same computer using SSH keys.

I set the `--global` user name and email to those of the first account, then I created a repository in my second account but when I did a push to the repo the user that made the commit appeared to be the user related to the first account, this was due to the global email I was using.

Is there a way to set the `user.name` and `user.email` based on the ssh key being used?

For now I deleted the global setting and put the local one in my repo but there might be a way to avoid setting the local email every time for every repo created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply configure the user.name and user.email of your second account in your local repo:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git config user.name secondName
git config user.email secondEmail
git add .
git commit -m "commit done with second account"
git push
```

The local config will overwrite the global config.

Note: the ssh key or url used for pushing is completely separate from the user.name used for the commits.

Comment: Yes I know I can set the name and email for the local repository, but it is quite boring to do the same every time. I don't know if it is possible but still there should be a way to get the email of the ssh-key used for the github account.

Comment: @BRabbit27 i understand, but you can only have one global setting. If it isn't the right one, you are left with local setting, and it isn't contextualized by the url.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll keep it as is. Unset the global settings and then for every repo use the local ones.